# Create a new text column to identify most recent file version

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which tracks file version history and would like to build a query to report on the most recent version of each file.

Current table structure:

```
fileID   fileName   fileVersion
 1        fileA      1.0.0
 2        fileB      1.0.0
 3        fileA      1.0.1
 4        fileC      1.0.0
 5        fileC      1.0.0
 6        fileA      1.0.2
```

What I would like:

```
fileID   fileName   fileVersion   currentVersion
 1        fileA      1.0.0         
 2        fileB      1.0.0         current
 3        fileA      1.0.1
 4        fileC      1.0.0
 5        fileC      1.0.1         current
 6        fileA      1.0.2         current
```

The older file versions can either be NULL or listed with a different string (old, previous, etc).

I was able to build a sub query to list the current versions using MAX(Version) and was trying to use that in a CASE statement with Exists or In to create the new column but could not get that to work.

```
Select t.*,
CASE When t.fileID Exists (sub query) Then 'current' Else NULL End As currentVersion
From t
```

Essentially, I can return all results and I can separately return just the recent versions but am looking for help with how to use the two queries together to create the currentVersion column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the window function Row_Number()

```
Declare @YourTable table (FileID int,fileName varchar(50),fileVersion varchar(50) )
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'fileA','1.0.0'),
(2,'fileB','1.0.0'),
(3,'fileA','1.0.1'),
(4,'fileC','1.0.0'),
(5,'fileC','1.0.1'),
(6,'fileA','1.0.2')

Select * 
      ,currentVersion_A =case when Row_Number() over (Partition By FileName Order by FileID desc) = 1 then 'Current' else '' end
      ,currentVersion_B =case when Row_Number() over (Partition By FileName Order by FileVersion desc) = 1 then 'Current' else '' end
      ,currentVersion_C =case when Row_Number() over (Partition By FileName Order by Cast(ParseName(FileVersion,3 ) as Int) desc,Cast(ParseName(FileVersion,2) as Int) desc,Cast(ParseName(FileVersion,1) as Int) desc) = 1 then 'Current' else '' end 
 from @YourTable
 Order by FileID

-- You have 3 options on how to determine Current (you know your data better than we do)
-- Use currentVersion_A IF FileID is an Identity() and each new version is added to the table
-- Use currentVersion_B IF and ONLY IF version will be 0 and 9
-- Use currentVersion_C As suggested by @HABO which is SMARTER provided the pattern is consistent
```

Returns

```
FileID      fileName    fileVersion currentVersion
1           fileA       1.0.0   
2           fileB       1.0.0       Current
3           fileA       1.0.1   
4           fileC       1.0.0   
5           fileC       1.0.1       Current
6           fileA       1.0.2       Current
```

Comment: Ordering by `FileVersion` will start to get _hinky_ when the various subfields exceed a single digit, e.g. "20.6.2" comes (alphabetically) before "3.0.1". You could use [`ParseName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as a hack to split the subfields out, convert them to integers and order them correctly.

Comment: @HABO My first instinct was to Order by FileID but I didn't want to make the assumption is was an Identity.

Comment: Using `Order by Cast( ParseName( FileVersion, 3 ) as Int ) desc, Cast( ParseName( FileVersion, 2 ) as Int ) desc, Cast( ParseName( FileVersion, 1 ) as Int ) desc` should handle any reasonable values in a proper numeric sort.

Comment: @HABO Great idea!  Never even occurred to me

Comment: If it makes a difference, fileID is a unique identity.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - The Row_Number function you suggested appears to accomplish exactly what I was looking for. However, I do not currently have a fileVersion which starts with a double digit to determine if there will be sorting orders as HABO pointed out.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - Since fileID is a unique identifier, I used option A and it worked perfectly and I don't have to worry about version number sorting. Thank you.

Comment: @dfek Note that "1.10.0" is alphabetically before "1.9.0". The problem occurs whenever a subfield has more than a single digit, not just the first subfield.